# How to pass parameters from one Page to another in Xamarin Forms? and How to Bind View (Page) and its ViewModel and initialize ViewModel object?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

How to pass parameters or objects from one Page to another in Xamarin Forms? I am having a Page containing some objects I want to pass them to another page

How to Bind View (Page) and its ViewModel and initialize ViewModel object in Xamarin Forms? What is the correct way to initialize ViewModel object inside View?

I have been figuring out how to achieve these 2 things in Xamarin Forms and finally, I have figured it out. Both the questions can be answered in one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the **MVVM** approach is recommended and it is quite simple. Just read it carefully as MVVM is very important when dealing with UI in Xamarin Forms

Suppose we have 2 Pages **HomePage** that accepts User's Name and on Submit we navigate to **UserDetailsPage** that displays the details of the user that we entered on the previous page. For simplicity we will only display User's Name on the **UserDetailsPage** and nothing else so that we will get to know how to pass parameters from one page to another using the MVVM approach.

So From **HomePage** I want to Navigate to **UserDetailsPage**.

**HomePage.xaml**

```xml
<Entry x:Name="nameEntryField" Placeholder="Enter your Name" />
<Button Text="Submit" Clicked="GoToUserDetailsPage" />
```

Hence in code behind of the **HomePage**, We will have

```cs
private void GoToUserDetailsPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserDetailsViewModel userDetailsViewModel = new UserDetailsViewModel();
    userDetailsViewModel.Name = nameEntryField.Text;
    Navigation.PushAsync(new UserDetailsPage(userDetailsViewModel)); // pass ViewModel object to next page
}
```

For this `View` Page we will create a `ViewModel` class as **UserDetailsViewModel.cs** inside **ViewModels** Folder

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MyApplication.ViewModels
{
    public class UserDetailsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name)); }
        }

        string name;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Now We will create **UserDetailsPage**

```cs
public partial class UserDetailsPage : ContentPage
{
    UserDetailsViewModel ViewModel = new UserDetailsViewModel();

    public UserDetailsPage(UserDetailsViewModel viewModel) // get viewModel object that will be passed from previous page
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = viewModel; // Initialize ViewModel object of this class with ViewModel object that we got from previous page hence it can be used inside this Page.
        BindingContext = ViewModel;
        string name = ViewModel.Name; // We will get the name that was entered in previous page
    }
}
```

In **XAML** of **UserDetailsPage** we can also add Label and display Name that we got from the previous page by setting its text property by binding to the ViewModel. We have already set `BindingContext = ViewModel;` of this page in the constructor. Just add `Label` like this

```xml
<Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
```

This will automatically set Label Text to the User's Name that we entered in the previous page.

In this way, by creating ViewModel and using the MVVM approach, we can pass objects of custom class i.e. Page's ViewModel class object.